# After clicking on an internal link in a PDF in Adobe Acrobat on iPad, how can I go back to the location of the text where the link is located?

Tags: ipad, pdf, links

After clicking on a internal link  in an PDF in Adobe Acrobat on iPad, how can I go back to the location of the text where the link is located?

Examples of internal link  in a [PDF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.03274.pdf) (green rectangles):

[image: link]

On Adobe Acrobat DC for Microsoft Windows I use the keyboard shortcut  <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> to go back to the location of the text where the internal link is located after clicking on it.

Comment: Are these web links which you've selected here?

Comment: @IconDaemon no web links, only internal links within the PDF